# Determine if a float number is irrational of a fraction

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

I have a random float number and I have to determine if it is an irrational number like √2 or a fraction like 123/321. Both of them are represented like an endless set of numbers anywhere but is there any way to definitely say whether a number is a fraction or it's irrational?

Thank you!

Comment: all numbers represented as floating point numbers in memory will be rational...

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to do it?..

Comment: It means your question is based on a false assumption (that there are any floating-point numbers that are irrational)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers are rational because the [mantissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) has a fixed length. Irrational numbers stored in floating point are truncated into rational numbers.

If you have a specific list of numbers you need to match, you can compare the random number to numbers on the list at a set floating point precision, but do keep in mind that you will get false positives due to truncation or rounding.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the list of numbers - they are random

Comment: You can create a list of floating point representations of some interesting irrational numbers (√2, √3, √5, ...) and then compare your random number to the numbers on the list. More generally, the question breaks down because for every terminating rational number with a fixed length mantissa, you can find a non-terminating irrational number that truncates to it.

Comment: Of course the list won't precisely because there are an infinite number of non-irrational numbers which are arbitrarily close to each irrational number. Thus, the chances of mislabeling are quite high (infinite, even).

Answer (score 2):

All (finite, non-NaN) floating point values are rational, because all finite (binary) floating-point numbers are of the form `f*2^e` for integers `f` and `e`.